# Cypress: When using Cucumber on Cypress Version 10, the Gherkin keyword 'And' does not seem to work anymore

Tags: cucumber, cypress, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have been using Cucumber, in version 9.5.2 of Cypress. I have now updated to Cypress version 10.9.0.
I have also been using the Gherkin keywords Given, Then, and When. I was using 'And' alongside some of those key words, but ever since I have updated to version 10, I have been getting the below error.

[image: Cypress Runner Log]

Is 'And' no longer supported? When I remove 'And' completely from my project, the Cypress tests burst back into life, and I don't get that error.

I have a 'common' folder which holds all the .js files for the Gherkin key words. I have been doing this because the project uses statements in these files over multiple tests.

[image: Common Folder Structure]

**Project package.json:**

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"stepDefinitions": [
  "cypress/e2e/components/**/*.{js,ts}",
  "cypress/e2e/common/**/*.{js,ts}"
],
"cucumberJson": {
  "generate": true,
  "fileSuffix": ".cucumber",
  "outputFolder": "results/cucumber"
}},
"devDependencies": {
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^13.0.2",
"@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.1.5",
"@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill": "^0.1.4",
"cypress": "^10.9.0",
"cypress-mailosaur": "^2.8.0"}}
```

**Project cypress.config.js:**

```
 e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
        },
        specPattern: ["**/*.feature", "cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{ js, jsx, ts, tsx }", "cypress/e2e/**/*.{feature,features}"],
    },
```

**Project plugins/index.js:**

[image: plugins/index]

Answer (score 0):

'And' and 'But' removed as part of v13.0.0 release of badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.

[image: @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor]

Answer (score 0):

From version 13.0.0 onwards the support for AND and BUT is removed.

https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/821

See Release Notes for v13.0.0 https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/releases